# "НЕ" с причастиями — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, причастия

Слитно или раздельно пишется "не" в следующих выражениях: практически незасоленные почвы, биологически несвязанный азот?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корректно: 1) *практически **не**засоленные почвы*, 2) *биологически **не**связанный азот*.

1) Здесь *практически* по смыслу равно *почти*; правило:

> При использовании в качестве пояснительных слов наречий меры и степени (весьма, крайне, очень, почти, совсем, вовсе и др.) **частица *не* с причастием пишется слитно**: *совершенно невычитанная рукопись; совсем непроверенные цифры*.

2) Причастие *несвязанный* здесь употреблено в значении прилагательного (ср. *неразлагающийся материал*):

> Если причастие употребляется в значении прилагательного, то и при наличии пояснительных слов **частица *не* пишется с причастием слитно**.

Источник: http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2249.

Answer (score 3):

**Практически незасоленные почвы, биологически несвязанный азот.**

Решение уже дано, но **желательно добавить некоторые пояснения.**

1) Наречие "практически" действительно чаще всего обозначает степень признака, например: **практически (почти) неисследованная** местность, слитное написание НЕ с причастием.

Но у этого наречия есть и другое значение - "в практическом отношении, на практике", и тогда НЕ с причастием будет писаться раздельно, например: Эта идея долго разрабатывалась, но так и осталась **практически не осуществленной**.

2) **Азот бывает свободным** (это молекулярный азот атмосферы), а бывает **химически связанным**, то есть существует в виде соединений, органических и неорганических. Если азот входит в состав органического соединения, то он называется биологически связанным. В то же время внутри живого растительного организма могут находится неорганические соединения, которые называют **биологически несвязанными.**

**Пример:** Повышается концентрация в растениях **биологически несвязанного** азота в виде нитратов и нитритов.

**Такова терминология**: азот бывает (1) несвязанный (свободный), (2) химически связанный, (3)биологически несвязанный (органически свободный, не входящий в органическую материю).

Answer (score 0):

Не с причастиями пишется слитно: 
1) Если оно полное, без зависимых слов или словами "крайне", "весьма",  "почти и т.д.
2) Если оно образовано от глагола с приставкой "недо"
В остальных случаях причастия с частицей пишутся раздельно. 
Здесь оба причастия пишутся слитно.